# Tengo que crear un programa que calcule el factorial y falla,

Tags: c++

tengo que buscar el factorial y no puedo. Compila pero no funciona: me da resultado 0 con cualquier numero que ingrese. Este es el programa que llevo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numero;
    int factorial;

    cout << "número para calcular el factorial:" << endl;
    cin >> numero;
    cout << "el factorial es: " << factorial << endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}

int factorial(int numero) {
    int factorial;
    if (numero <= 1) {
        factorial = numero * factorial;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: factorial no deberia estar declarado?

Comment: si lo esta, no puse todo el codigo. Lo pondre todo

Comment: Eso que muestras no compila.

Comment: no puedo agregar todo el codido.

Comment: Agrégalo como texto y luego se edita.

Comment: listo, lo agregue todo

Comment: compi, falta codigo, eso no puede complilar

Comment: ahora debería compilar, lo probe y el código si me compila pero me sigue apareciendo el 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int factorial(int numero){
  int factorial;
  if(numero<=1){
    factorial=numero*factorial;
    return 1;
}
```

Lo que hace la función:

- Si numero > 1, no entra en el if, devuelve sin hacer un return explícito. La función puede devolver cualquier valor.
- Si numero <= 1, entra en el if, multiplica numero por un valor indefinido (la variable factorial) y ese valor no lo usa sino que la función devuelve 1.

Lo que tiene que hacer:

- Si numero <= 1, devuelve 1.
- Si numero > 1, devuelve ese número por el resultado de llamar a la función factorial de nuevo, pero pasándole número - 1.

Así, factorial(4) será 4*factorial(3) = 4 * 3 * factorial(2) = 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1). Como factorial (1) = 1 --> 4 * 3 * 2 * 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Tomando en cuenta la recrusividad**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long double factorial(int);
int main(){   
    int n;
    cout << "Introduzca numero: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "factorial: " << factorial(n) << endl;
}
long double factorial(int n){
     long double fact;
     if (n==0)
        return 1;
     else
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: Dado que el factorial es un número entero, no hay necesidad de utilizar reales (`long double`). En su lugar sería mejor utilizar `unsigned long long int`, al menos para ser consistentes con la definición matemática del factorial.

Comment: Es correcto... Con esa modificación queda perfecto. ;)